# How to select columns of different lengths

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of part numbers along with many of their properties like such:

```
[Part Number] [Type] [Manager] [Cat. Code] [etc...]
  AAA-001       A      Dave       123
  DDD-008       D      Chris      153
  BBB-003       B      Dave       254
  CCC-008       C      Dave       153
  ...
```

I'm trying to make a list of all the unique values of each property so it looks more like this:

```
[Type] [Manager] [Cat. Code] [etc...]
  A      Dave       123
  B      Chris      153
  C                 254
  D
```

However whenever I try to do this using SELECT DISTINCT * or the like, it fills up all the columns so that they're the same length as the longest one, filled horizontally according to the original table:

```
[Type] [Manager] [Cat. Code] [etc...]
  A      Dave       123
  B      Dave       254
  C      Dave       153
  D      Chris      153
```

How do I stop this from happening, and just keep unique values of each column, even if they might be different lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what DISTINCT does. It will filter your results so that all *rows* returned are unique, not each column. Depending which columns are named in your SELECT, you'll get different results. For an example, see http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php and the section "Example - With Multiple Expressions"

For your case, if you want lists of the unique values in each column, then you'll have to do a separate query on each column, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Type] FROM [Parts]
SELECT DISTINCT [Manager] FROM [Parts]
...etc
```

If you then want them side-by-side (as per your sample desired output), you'll just have to copy and paste them into a spreadsheet or something.

Comment: Sounds tedious. But I guess if that's the only way it'll have to do. Thank you

Comment: @Kiplacon sorry but, yes it is :-) You can't do all the columns together because by looking for unique values in each, you're effectively removing any relationship between the columns. The items on each row might from anywhere in the original table, so there's no way to associate them with that's on the same row of the next column of unique values. That's why they're separate queries.